# MongoDB and Mocha

Tags: mongodb, mocha.js

Has anyone ever used async/await in their mocha tests?

I'm creating this simple test to check if my code successfully saves an object to the database:

```
const mocha = require('mocha');
const assert = require('assert');
const marioChar = require('../models/mariochar');

async function saveAMarioChar (paramname,paramweight) {
    var char = new marioChar({
        name: paramname,
        weight: paramweight
    });

    const saveresult = await char.save()
    return !saveresult.isNew;

} 

describe(
    'saving record',

    () => {

        it('Save a mariochar',
            async ()  => {
                const result = await saveAMarioChar('luigi',64);
                assert(result)
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble guys, this code is working fine, I used "mongooose" with a triple "o" on my schema creation.